# Brewing in former lotion pot

Tags: wort, cleaning, boil-kettle, brewpot

Some relatives recently gave me a 6-gallon aluminum pot that they no longer wanted. The pot was used to make homemade lotion. I've been needing a bigger brew pot, but money has been tight. I'm excited to get one for free!

I've washed the pot many time and also boiled water in it with various combinations of cheap dish soap, vinegar, and a pinch of salt. (This was how I was advised to clean it.)

I'm not concerned about metallic tastes in the wort, but I'm unsure what impact the lotion will have on it. Do you guys think this pot will be OK for brewing? Or cooking in general?

Comment: Try boiling some water in it for a few minutes, then let it cool and drink it.  If that water is fine, your beer should be fine.

Comment: I've had someone else taste it, and they said it was fine. I unfortunately can't taste subtleties in food or drinks :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the cleaning you gave it will be good. But if not, then at most your first beer might have a flat head from fatty deposits that will be removed by the acidic wort on your first brew.

So definitely use it, you'll be fine in the long run.